# Spring MVC Autocomplete can not get value from json

Tags: jquery, json, jsp, spring-mvc, autocomplete

I write example about autocomplete spring mvc and jquery/json. I using spring and hibernate get object value from json but when I search it not work. I have getting from database but autocomplete not list value dropdown, Please anyone help me this issue.

- My User

  ```
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String country;
  public User() {
  } 
  public User(String name, String country) {
  this.name;
  this.country;
  }
  // getter and setter
  ...
  ```
- My Service(UserServiceImpl.java)

  ```
  @Repository
  public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
      @Autowired
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public List<String> getCountryList(String query) {

          List<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();

          Query queryList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM user u WHERE u.country LIKE '%"+query+"%'");
          countries = queryList.list();
          query = query.toLowerCase();

          return countries;
      }
  }
  ```
- My Controller(UserController):

  ```
      @Controller
      public class UserController {

      @Autowired
      private UserService userService;

      @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView index() {
          User userForm = new User();
          return new ModelAndView("user", "userForm", userForm);
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/get_country_list", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*")
      public @ResponseBody List<String> getCountryList(@RequestParam("term") String query) {
          List<String> countryList = userService.getCountryList(query);   
          return countryList;
      }
  ```
- My jsp (user.jsp)

  ```
  <body>
  <h2>Spring MVC Autocomplete with JQuery &amp; JSON example</h2>
  <form:form method="post" action="save.html" modelAttribute="userForm">
  <table>
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <td><form:input path="country" id="country" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
          <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <br />

  </form:form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
       function split(val) {
          return val.split(/,\s*/);
       }
       function extractLast(term) {
          return split(term).pop();
       }

      $(document).ready(function) { 
          $( "#country" ).autocomplete({
              source: function (request, response) {
              $.getJSON("${pageContext. request. contextPath}/get_country_list.html", {
                  term: extractLast(request.term)
              }, response);
          },
          search: function () {
              // custom minLength
              var term = extractLast(this.value);
              if (term.length < 1) {
                  return false;
              }
          },
          focus: function () {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
              return false;
          },
          select: function (event, ui) {
              var terms = split(this.value);
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push(ui.item.value);
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push("");
              this.value = terms.join(", ");
              return false;
          }
          });
    });
  </script>

  </body>
  ```

I have test autocomplete by firebug and json response values success

```
Object { id=1, name="john", country="london", more...}
Object { id=2, name="johanson", country="london", more...}
```

and it has dropdown but value not display in autocomplete. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

In UserRepositoryImpl.java file change the query as below

Query queryList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("Select u.country FROM user u WHERE u.country LIKE '%"+query+"%'");